# Why maximum acceleration a man can get on walking along a rough surface is $μ$g?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

Suppose a Man is running on a road which is a rough surface with friction coefficient $μ$. Why will the maximum acceleration of man which he can get is $μ$? Why not from himself by internal body mechanism he cant get a max acceleration greater than $μg$ ? [My thoughts if he is running and is not slipping with respect to ground then the FBD of man will always have friction as a force which can provide him acceleration and that cant be maximum than the limiting friction value which is $μ_s mg$, hence max acc is $μg$? ] [If he was running with slipping then he might have greater accelration due to his body ?]

Comment: *Why will the maximum acceleration of man which he can get is μg?* What is the origin of this statement?

Comment: Origin is this problem Sir :Suppose man is walking along a road with some velocity v how much time does it takes for him to make his velocity 2v if the time needs to be taken minimum ? [He is walking along a straight road]

Comment: $\mu mg $ is the maximum FRICTION FORCE, not the overall force on the man

Comment: Whats the overall force @jensen paull ? Only friction is shown in the fbd isnt Sir ?

Comment: Though yeah normal and weight is there but other than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only external force acting forward on the man is the friction force by the ground which is equal to and opposite to the force the man exerts backwards on the ground per Newton’s third law. The maximum possible static friction force before slipping occurs is $\mu_{s} mg$. Where $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction. That  equals the maximum acceleration of the man or $\mu_{s} mg=ma$ and $a=\mu_{s} g$.

In effect, the external static friction force does positive work on the man since its direction is the same as the directly of the man’s motion. More importantly, unlike kinetic friction, static friction is not dissipative, i.e., it does not result in energy loss due to heating.

But once the maximum possible static friction force is reached,  friction transitions from static to kinetic and slipping occurs where $\mu_k$ is now the coefficient of kinetic friction and in general $\mu_{k}<\mu_s$. Now the kinetic friction force is constant and opposes the sliding motion between the foot and ground. In effect kinetic friction does negative work since its force is opposite the direction of the sliding motion between the foot and the ground. The negative work done by friction takes energy away from the  work done pushing back on the ground on for a net work of zero and the energy dissipated as heat (which does not occur with static friction). The end result after slipping occurs is the man continues, but at constant velocity.

This is perhaps easier to visualize if we consider the acceleration of a car, which is due to the static friction force acting forward in response to the torque applied to the drive wheel(s). Once slipping occurs, the negative work done by kinetic friction equals the positive work done by the torque on the wheel equals for a net work of zero and no change in kinetic energy (no further acceleration) of the car. If the torque applied to the wheel increases slipping also increases and the corresponding negative work by kinetic friction increases, for a net work of zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir i got this point but then whats the reason of man to stop at a point as how does he reduce his velocity ? Are we giving like a command to friction to change direction hence this result ?

Comment: He doesn’t stop but is no longer able to maintain the maximum acceleration due to slipping. The same happens to a car. Friction now becomes kinetic friction and the coefficient of kinetic friction is less than static friction

Comment: Got that Sir thanks and Sir by newtons third law we can say confirmly that man cant be able exceed umg force to be applied to ground from his foot in any scenario of possible outcomes ?

Comment: Since the friction force is limited by the friction coefficient and the weight of the man, both considered constant the max force the man can exert on the ground is likewise limited to the same amount by Newton’s third law

Comment: @BobD The problem is that as the man puts his foot down the normal force will have to be larger than mμg to reduce its downward speed.

Comment: @Farcher yes, but isn't the timing of these two separate motions different. In other words,  the downward force decelerates the vertical motion but once the foot is down and begins to push backwards the downward force becomes the weight (normal force for friction).

Comment: @Orion_Pax I have updated my answer to cover our follow up discussions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sir if you are saying he will move with constant velocity i still dont why its required as such the man also needs to stop right ? So the kinetic friction work reduces his speed to zero? During the whole journey?

Comment: @BobD The body/leg will accelerate upwards as swell as forwards? Just an idea.

Comment: @Orion_Pax No, no, no. The man would stop only if he stopped exerting a backward force and simply skid to a stop, because then the kinetic friction force would then be the only force and would oppose his forward sliding motion causing him to decelerate and come to a stop.

Comment: Sir you meant other than friction there is another force which is horizontal and contributing in running and slowing down ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax Sorry, but I just can't seem to get through to you and have no more time to spend on this. Good luck!

Comment: Okay no problem Sir i will try to understand again from your comments

Answer (score 1):

The starting point in understanding this is to remember that momentum always has to be conserved. That means that if you are standing still on the road and you then start to accelerate- that is, to increase your momentum- you need to impart an equal but opposite change of momentum to the Earth, so that overall there is no change to the total momentum.  You do this by pressing backwards (ie opposite to your direction of motion) on the road. However, if you press too hard, your feet will slip, because the force you re trying to apply will exceed the grip provided by friction, which is m. Given that the force you can apply is limited to m, and your mass is m, the maximum acceleration you can achieve is g.

Comment: Sir thanks i understood , what happens when he applies more than umg force on the ground ? Will he fell down ? And by newtons third law wont always force by man on ground and by ground needs to be equal ? So man can never be able to execute greater than umg force as by ground only umg possible ?

Comment: If he tries to apply a force greater than m his feet will slip.

Comment: Hmm yeah Sir then it will change to ukmg but one thing as the man is applying a force greater than usmg but from ground max friction is ukmg when he is slipping , so as these two forces are not equal doesnt this violate the third law of motion ?

Comment: No, because when he slips he he loses his grip and that prevents him from applying a greater force.

Comment: Hmm nice point thanks Sir